# Dynamically import python module

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have the following project structure:

```
python/
..core/
..envs/
  ..default/
  ....__init__
  ....default.py
  ..dev1/
  ....__init__
  ....dev1.py
dynamic_inventory.py
```

in `dev1` i have the following:

```
from ..default.default import BaseInventory
```

in dynamic_inventory:

```
import inspect
from envs.dev1 import dev1
print inspect.getmembers(dev1, inspect.isclass)
```

it gives me right code:

```
> [('BaseInventory', <class 'envs.default.default.BaseInventory'>),
> ('BatchProcessor', <class 'envs.dev1.dev1.BatchProcessor'>), ...
```

but dynamically:

```
import inspect

sys.path.append("python/envs")
m = __import__("dev1")
print inspect.getmembers(m, inspect.isclass)
```

`gives me: []`

how to do import module dynamically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

Firstly, when you write `from envs.dev1 import dev1` you are importing `dev1` from the `envs.dev1` package. But with `__import__("dev1")`, you are importing it as a standalone module.

Secondly: with `sys.path.append("python/envs"); __import__("dev1")` you are importing `python/envs/dev1/__init__.py`, because the `python/envs` directory contains the `dev1` directory. But you want the `python/envs/dev1/dev1.py` file. That's why you are getting an empty list: your `__init__.py` does not define any class.

Putting everything together:

```
import inspect

# no sys.path manipulation
dev1 = __import__('envs.dev1.dev1', fromlist=['dev1'])
print inspect.getmembers(dev1, inspect.isclass)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!